# How to use non-integer, float values for tkinter Scale widget scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, slide, tkinter-scale

I need to set the scale from 0.55 to 2.75 with a very little interval for my slide

But all I get is a range from 1 to 3 with a scale of 1. Totally annoying.
TkInter documentation says it can handle floating values, so what's wrong?

```
Scale(window,label='Set Value', from_=0.55, to=2.75, tickinterval=0.001).pack()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that setting the option `resolution` instead of `tickinterval` (which you have set) to 0.01 or even 0.001 will cause it to at least to retrieve the value of scrollbar in that precision, e.g. 2.15 or 2.150. That could also allow you to set float values to `from` and `to` options, but I can't test it now, so it's highly possible that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your interval is 0.01, you can try this.

```
Scale(frame, from_=0.55, to=2.75, digits = 3, resolution = 0.01, label = "Lower").pack()
```

You will get (digits-1) number of decimals. (In this case 2). So, 0.55,0.56, 0.57 ....., 2.75